# Is it possible to embed the built in comment form inside another form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-comments

I have a form to edit information about something as it may change. What I would like to do is to use Django comments to require that when editing the information, the user doing the editing provide a comment stating what they did, ex "fixed typo in name." Is it possible to embed the comment form in my other form while not requiring any of the fields except the comment field?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a hack called superform.py:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3206463/57812

There is also this project for nested forms:
https://github.com/dszczyt/django-nested-forms